# calculate radius of a circle using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

I am trying to calculate radius of a circle using javascript. I have following section with css

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="circle"></section>
```

As the width and height of this circle is 100x100. **How can I calculate its radius?**

Comment: Simply divide the width/height of the box by 2. For instance: `var radius = document.querySelector('.circle').offsetWidth / 2`

Answer (score 3):

Since the radius is just half of the diameter, this is easy. The diameter is 100px, per `width` and `height`. Hence, radius is 100px / 2 = 50px.

Answer (score 1):

While you could set the radius relatively by `border-radius: 50%`, you could simply divide the `width`/`height` of the box by `2` to get the radius.

For instance:

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('.circle'),
    radius = circle.offsetWidth / 2;

circle.innerHTML = "Radius: " + radius + "px";
```

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border-radius: 50%; /* I don't know if you really need to get the value of this */
  background: red;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="circle"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to set a radius to make a perfect circle, use `50%` radius. This way it doesn't depend on width/height and you don't need javascript:

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="circle"></section>
```